# How do I align a search bar and search button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to align search button next to search bar but I don't know how to do it.

HTML :

```
<div id="tmsearch">
 <span class="btn-toogle active"></span>
  <form id="tmsearchbox" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="position"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderway" value="desc"/>
    <input class="tm_search_query form-control" type="text" id="tm_search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?"/>
    </form>
    <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE ==> https://jsfiddle.net/bpr6qmjt/3/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS style "display:inline"

```
<div id="tmsearch">
 <span class="btn-toogle active"></span>
  <form id="tmsearchbox" method="get" style="display:inline">
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="position"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderway" value="desc"/>
    <input class="tm_search_query form-control" type="text" id="tm_search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?"/>
    </form>
    <button style="display:inline">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easy add style `display:inline-block` to the form element.
like this

```
<form id="tmsearchbox" method="get" style="display:inline-block">
```

or you can add it by id

```
form#tmsearchbox { display :inline-block }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the style of the form in CSS:

```
#tmsearchbox {display:inline;}
```

Or embedded the style in the form tag:

```
<form id="tmsearchbox" method="get" style="display:inline;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="tmsearchbox" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="position">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderway" value="desc">
    <input class="tm_search_query form-control" id="myinput" type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?" style="
    float: left;
">
    </form>
```